# MySQL to PostgreSQL table create conversion - charset and collation

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I want to migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL.My query for create table is like this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS conftype 
(
  CType char(1) NOT NULL,
  RegEx varchar(300) default NULL,  
  ErrStr varchar(300) default NULL,
  Min integer default NULL,
  Max integer default NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (CType)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin;
```

What is the converted form of this query. I am confused with  `DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin` part. How can I convert this part?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That one would mean that the *table* uses only latin-1 (iso-8859-1) character set and latin-1 binary sorting order. In PostgreSQL the character set is *database-wide*, there is no option to set it on table level.

You could create a [mostly compatible database with](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/multibyte.html):

```
 CREATE DATABASE databasenamegoeshere WITH ENCODING 'LATIN1' LC_COLLATE='C'
     LC_CTYPE='C' TEMPLATE=template0;
```

However, I personally would consider a MySQL->PostgreSQL port also worthy of switching to UTF-8/Unicode.

Answer (score 4):

The character set is defined when you create the database, you can't overwrite that per table in Postgres.

A non-standard collation can be defined only on column level in Postgres, not on table level. I think(!) that the equivalent to `latin1_bin` in MySQL would be the `"C"` collation in Postgres.

So if you do need a different collation, you need something like this

```
RegEx varchar(300) default NULL collate "C",  
ErrStr varchar(300) default NULL collate "C",
```

---

<sup>`min` and `max` are reserved wordds in SQL and you shouldn't use them as column names (although using them as column names will work I strongly suggest you find different names to avoid problems in the future)</sup>