# Symfony/Doctrine - Search

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

could someone help me with basic search? 
I just can't figure it out.
My search works only if I type 1 word. But if I type 2,3,4,... words it doesn't work.

**Example**: POLYKARBONÁTOVÉ POUZDRO NA MACBOOK *(Polycarbonate cover for Macbook)*

If I type to search input just "pouzdro" it returns all covers. 
If I type "Polykarbonátové pouzdro" it return nothing.
If I type "Polykarbonátové" it returns nothing.

Here is my code:

```
    if ($keyword != null) {
        $keyword = strtolower(preg_replace('/\p{Mn}/u', '', \Normalizer::normalize($keyword, \Normalizer::FORM_KD)));
        $keywords = explode(' ', $keyword);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($keywords as $key) {
            $i++;
            if ($i == 1) {
                $qb->where("p.title LIKE :keyword$i");
            } else {
                $qb->andWhere("p.title LIKE :keyword$i");
            }
            $qb->setParameter("keyword$i", "%" . $key . "%");
        }
    }
```

Thank you :)

EDIT:
Query from the log(I am using postgresql):

> [2016-10-26 16:47:11] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT p0_.id AS id_0,
>   p0_.serial_number AS serial_number_1, p0_.title AS title_2, p0_.url AS
>   url_3, p0_.note AS note_4, p0_.views AS views_5, p0_.price AS price_6,
>   p0_.bought_price AS bought_price_7, p0_.old_price AS old_price_8,
>   p0_.is_active AS is_active_9, p0_.is_accessory AS is_accessory_10,
>   p0_.is_special AS is_special_11, p0_.quantity AS quantity_12,
>   p0_.created_at AS created_at_13, p0_.updated_at AS updated_at_14,
>   p0_.details_id AS details_id_15, p0_.accessory_category_id AS
>   accessory_category_id_16 FROM products p0_ WHERE p0_.title LIKE ?
>   ["%polykarbonatove%"] []
>
> [2016-10-26 16:53:52] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT p0_.id AS id_0,
>   p0_.serial_number AS serial_number_1, p0_.title AS title_2, p0_.url AS
>   url_3, p0_.note AS note_4, p0_.views AS views_5, p0_.price AS price_6,
>   p0_.bought_price AS bought_price_7, p0_.old_price AS old_price_8,
>   p0_.is_active AS is_active_9, p0_.is_accessory AS is_accessory_10,
>   p0_.is_special AS is_special_11, p0_.quantity AS quantity_12,
>   p0_.created_at AS created_at_13, p0_.updated_at AS updated_at_14,
>   p0_.details_id AS details_id_15, p0_.accessory_category_id AS
>   accessory_category_id_16 FROM products p0_ WHERE p0_.title LIKE ? AND
>   p0_.title LIKE ? ["%polykarbonatove%","%pouzdro%"] []

Answer (score 0):

So,

1. You don't really need this

   ```
   LOWER() // LIKE is not case sensitive
   ```
2. Try to clear your code, you should code on this way

   ```
   foreach ($keywords as $key) {
       $i++;
       if ($i == 1) {
           $qb->where("p.title LIKE :keyword$i");
       } else {
           $qb->andWhere("p.title LIKE :keyword$i");
       }
       $qb->setParameter("keyword$i", "%" . $key . "%");
   }
   ```
3. Can you open the log file and give us the real query which doctrine tried (var/cache/logs/dev.log)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you encountered isn't about the number of searched terms, but about accents.

If you want to perform a search without accents, you can change the collation to `utf8_general_ci`, which is accent insensitive.

To change the collation with Doctrine, you'll have to implement a custom DQL function, as explained [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) and implemented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22329839/4074148) from [hattila](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1389340/hattila):

```
namespace MyCompany\MyBundle\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class CollateFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    public $expressionToCollate = null;
    public $collation = null;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->expressionToCollate = $parser->StringPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $lexer = $parser->getLexer();
        $this->collation = $lexer->token['value'];

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return sprintf( '%s COLLATE %s', $this->expressionToCollate->dispatch($sqlWalker), $this->collation );
    }
}
```

Then add it to Symfony [as explained here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html).

Comment: Thanks, so it should be  ? or $qb->where("p.title LIKE COLLATE(:keyword$i, utf8_general_ci)"); ? Cause I got this: 
SQLSTATE[42704]: Undefined object: 7 ERROR: collation "utf8_general_ci" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist

Comment: After researching about your error, it seems you'll have to change the collation of the entire database to the collation `C` since postgresql doesn't allow to change collation like that. I suggest you look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35795540/4074148 or others, but I think it's outside the scope of this question.